# How do I make my function return the x coordinates of my turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-3.5

```
import turtle

tess = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()

def hello3 (x,y):
   tess.goto(x, y)

   return tess.xcor()
```

I want my function hello3 to return the x coordinate of my turtle after I click somewhere on the screen, but it seems to return None all the time.

```
turtle.onscreenclick(hello3, btn=1)
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking.  the function hello3 will be called each time user clicks mouse on screen.  It will not be able to return anything to your program.

Comment: yes i know that, I am asking how can I make it return the x coordinate or as you you said it does't return anything, then why?

Comment: @AlexMurray, what makes you think it returns `None`? That is, precisely what test do you run, what results do you observe, and how do those results differ from what you expect?

Comment: @Robᵩ , from my limited knowledge of programming the test I did was print(turtle.onscreenclick(hello3, btn=1)), which in my understanding should print the x coordinate to the console screen. But it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

When you call turtle.onscreenclick(hello3, btn=1), it binds the 'hello3' function to the screen-click event. However, it will not call the 'hello3' function immediately. When there is a screen-click event, the program will call 'hello3' function. Therefore, the turtle.onscreenclick() returns None, because it connects a function to the event but doesn't call the function. Try the following code:

```
import turtle

tess = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()

def hello3(x,y):
    tess.goto(x, y)

    # When you click the screen, it will print out its x-coordinate. 
    print tess.xcor()

    # You cannot receive this return value, if you put this function 
    # as a call-back function (or completion handler). 
    return tess.xcor()

returnValue = turtle.onscreenclick(hello3, btn=1)
print type(returnValue)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Ya it prints the value of x coordinate to the screen and the type is NoneType, but the reason I wanted my function to return the x coordinate is because I wanted to use that value in a different function. Is  there any way to do so?

Comment: @AlexMurray I think you have to call that function, which needs the x-coordinate, inside the 'hello3' function. In this case, you can make sure that when you get a new x-coordinate, that function will be called. Alternatively, you have to define a global variable to store the x-coordinate. When you put the 'hello3' as a call-back function, it can be treated as an action (not a normal function call) that only do something without a return value.